# Not able to redirect domain in Heroku (DNS)

Tags: heroku, dns

I'm having hard times trying to redirect a custom domain on Heroku, have you guys had the same problem?

1. Configured custom domain on Heroku (already tried different variation):
   [image]
2. The server asks for Server Name, so I add the only thing Heroku returns as the DNS:

[image]

3. Below there are two domains, the first says "servfail" (the current app domain), the second "nxdomain", which I've just bought it's fine.

[image]

Any advices? Should I deploy on another server? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those facing DNS redirecting problems in Heroku, I suggest this Add-on that you can add to your app in Heroku (for free): **PointDNS**

With it you can get many types of adresses, including IP and/or n1.server n2.server and so on, in which you can add the address to your domain settings.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the DNS servers of your domain fariba.cl to fariba.cl.herokudns.com at the domain registrar's end (from where you purchased the domain)

After that it will work fine.